# How to select specific part in string using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

So I am working with recursion,

The problem is:

`" Good(43) Morning"`

I have to use recursion to print all the information inside parenthesis like this: `"(43)"`

My code so far is:

```
def extractor(myString):
    if len(myString) == 0:
        return ""



    if myString[0] == "(":
        return myString[0]
    if myString[0] == ")":
        return myString[:]
    else:
        return extractor(myString[1:])
```

I can only get parenthesis. How could I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
def extractor(myString):
    if not myString:  # empty strings are falsy
        return ""
    if myString[0] == "(":
        if myString[-1] == ")": # success
            return myString
        else:  # only starts with (, trim from the end
            return extractor(myString[:-1])
    else:  # doesn't start with (, trim from beginning
        return extractor(myString[1:])
```

Comment: That's work but I can not use any build in function except len()

Comment: `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` are methods, not functions, but fair enough, I'll change it.

Comment: @David.Lin Am I correct input is "(43)" & not " Good(43) Morning" to function extractor

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, here is an iterative version of your code. :)

```
def iterative_extractor(mystring):
    if not mystring:
        return ""

    while mystring[0] != "(" or mystring[-1] != ")":
        if mystring[0] != "(":
            mystring = mystring[1:]
        else:
            mystring = mystring[:-1]
    return mystring
```

OR:

```
def iterative_extractor(mystring):
    if not mystring:
        return ""

    while mystring[0] != "(":
        mystring = mystring[1:]

    while mystring[-1] != ")":
        mystring = mystring[:-1]

    return mystring
```

Output:

```
mystring = "Lol (234) mate!"
print(iterative_extractor(mystring))
>>> "(234)"
```